# How to quote a shell command containing a quote

Tags: bash, shellcheck

I'm struggling to fix the following shellcheck warning, because it would require nested quotes:

```
here=$(dirname $(realpath "$0" 2> /dev/null || grealpath "$0"))
               ^-- SC2046 (warning): Quote this to prevent word splitting.
```

How could I write this in a safe way with everything correctly quoted?

Comment: Double quotes and `$(...)` can be nested without problems.

Comment: Even with correct quoting, the code in the question won't work in general.  See [BashFAQ/028 (How do I determine the location of my script? ...)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) (particularly the [Why $0 is NOT an option](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028#Why_.240_is_NOT_an_option) section).